# Is it allowed to transport a small gas container, for a camping stove, in the luggage?

Tags: air-travel, luggage, camping

I am planning to go camping abroad. I am taking a camping stove, but I am not sure I can take the gas bottle ([kind of like this one](https://www.google.com/search?q=camping%20gaz&hl=en&client=ubuntu&hs=Msc&channel=fs&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=AoAsUbW6NYGR0AWogYGgDQ&ved=0CF8QsAQ&biw=1615&bih=962#imgrc=HfvJHYXG1GCEQM%3a;1cNEdOq827ShvM;http%253A%252F%252Fwww.outdooraction.co.nz%252Fmedia%252Fcatalog%252Fproduct%252Fcache%252F1%252Fimage%252F9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95%252Fc%252Fa%252Fcampinggaz190.jpg;http%253A%252F%252Fwww.outdooraction.co.nz%252Fcamping-gaz-190g.html;800;800))

Of course I can buy one at the destination, but I am not sure where and how I will find one. It would be more practical just to carry it.

Am I allowed to carry this in the check-in luggage?

Comment: IMO you're not allowed to do this. In the container there will be some gas residue

Comment: Already asked here http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13816/camping-stove-on-a-plane Don't forget to search before asking !

Comment: It's not exactly the same question as far as I can tell. But the information given on the other question is of help

Answer (score 6):

OK, this question is for the gas bottle, the [other one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/13816/camping-stove-on-a-plane) was for the camping stove.

For the gas bottle, it's clearly no.

[Prohibited Items on TSA.gov](http://www.tsa.gov/traveler-information/prohibited-items#9)
Check the website of any airline and i think you will find it in the list of things you can't take.